# How to call bat file using jsp where bat file is located on server

Tags: jsp

How do I call a .bat file using JSP where the .bat file is located on the web server.
I have already tried to run the .bat file using the web application.
Suggestions welcome.

Comment: what code did you try in your jsp?

Comment: runtime.exec("Path")